# Pluralization issue in too-long title error message, when title is 151 characters

Tags: bug, asking-questions, character-limit, plurals

In the question title after trying to add more than 150 characters, there is a warning displayed over the title box.

After entering the 151th character, the warning is displayed as "Too long by 1 character**s**"

Can this be fixed?

Screenshot for reference:

[image]

Comment: This is one of those things you shouldn't even try. 150 characters in a title, that's a small paragraph.

Comment: In SE sites with eg MathJax enabled you can sometimes reach the maximum character limit with relatively few symbols (in particular not a small paragraph)

Comment: @Mast better having precise questions than a short generic title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This pluralisation problems has been fixed
[image]